# Node.js REPL function docstring

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

Theseday, I start the node.js. I have a problem in nodejs REPL.

When I use Python, I just use "?" method to check the function's docstring ( in python repl, ipython too)

[image]

That's cos function structure in ipython by using "math.cos?" order.

Otherwise, I can't find a this method in node.js repl. This function is very necessary when we do programming.

Can you give me a some tip for checking docstring in node.js ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/docstring

Comment: @AyushGupta sorry. I didn't intent the docstring function. I want to know the structure and docstring. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid there is no build in command to check the function’s structure or docstring in **node-repl** right now as you can do in **python-repl** or **ipython**. But the good new is [the contributors](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8493) are already working on a feature like this.

For the time being you can use [node-help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-help) or [node-repl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-repl) as an alternative. Although they are not good enough, they should work for now.